# Google script won't sent out the emails using Gmailapp.sendemail()

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to use google script to send out some automation emails based on values from a google sheet. all the variables are not in HTML format for the email body or email subject. the execution is complete but no email received. here is the sample code:

```
   if(activitytype == "CTV" && datectvreceived == ""){
     if(firstattemp == "" && 5000 >firstattempdays > 1){

       var logic1message = l1content1 + plemail + l1content2 + ccemail +  l1content3 + pvcemail + l1content4 +protocolNum + l1content5 + protocolNum + '-'+ studytitle + l1content6 + reportperiod + l1content7;


           GmailApp.sendEmail(pvoemail,'First Attempt Reminder: ' +protocolNum ,logic1message);
       }// first logic 

    else if(firstattemp != "" && secondattemp == "" && 5000>secondattempdays > 7){

      var logic2message = l2content1 + plemail + l2content2 + ccemail+ l2content3 + pvcemail + l2content4 + protocolNum + l2content5 + protocolNum + '-' + studytitle + l2content6 + reportperiod + l2content7 + firstattemp + l2content8;
            GmailApp.sendEmail(pvoemail,'Second Attempt Reminder: '+ protocolNum,logic2message);

       } //second logic

    else if(secondattemp != "" && firstattemp != "" && thirdattemp == "" && 5000>thirdattempdays > 7){
      var logic3message = l3content1 + plemail + l3content2 + ccemail + l3content3 + pvcemail + l3content4 + protocolNum + l3content5 + protocolNum + '-' + studytitle + l3content6 + reportperiod + l3content7 + firstattemp + '&' + secondattemp + l3content8;

            GmailApp.sendEmail(pvoemail,'Third Attempt Reminder: ' + protocolNum,logic3message);

    } // third logic

    else if (thirdattemp != "" &&  secondattemp != "" && firstattemp != "" &&srtattemp == "" && 5000 >srtattempday > 7){
      var logicsrtmessage = lscontent1 + plemail + lscontent2 +ccemail + lscontent3 + pvcemail + lscontent4 + firstattemp + lscontent5 + secondattemp + lscontent6 + thirdattemp + lscontent7;

            GmailApp.sendEmail(pvoemail,'SRT Esaclation Reminder: '+ protocolNum,logicsrtmessage);

    } //srt logic

    sheet.getRange(startRow +i, 26).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); // a note for the protocols which email were sent
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();}
    else {sheet.getRange(startRow +i, 26).setValue(No_Email_Sent);
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

please advice. thank you guys!!!!!

Comment: You have not provide a [mcve]   pvoemail and logicsrtmessage are both undefined

Comment: Execution transcripts, console logs?

Comment: the pvoemail is the email from the google sheet. it will be changing row by row. and I defined the pvo email before and I did;t posted it yet. also, the logicsrtmessage is defined as the combination of many contents which pulled from google Sheets as well. thank you!

Comment: can I know how to add console log to my code?

Comment: Depending on the context you may have to do something different.  If running from script editor include `console.log(logic1message );` right after `var logic1message`.  If running from a menu item then `Logger.log(logic1message )` and then check the Execution log.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change all your if, else if(s)

```
if(firstattemp == "" && 5000 >firstattempdays > 1){
```

This is equivalent to

```
if( ( firstattemp == "" )  && ( ( 5000 >firstattempdays ) > 1) ) {
```

So ( 5000 >firstattempdays ) is either true or false

and ( true > 1 ) is false and ( false > 1 ) is also false

Change these to

```
if( ( firstattemp == "" ) && ( 5000 > firstattempdays ) && ( firstattempdays > 1) ) {
```

Comment: Hi, the email was sent out!!! but there is no body content in the email. can I know why? maybe it is the cell value is plain text in the google sheet?

Comment: Much of your script is not shown, so there is no way for me to tell why the body is empty.